# How to pluck multiple attributes with nil values in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a User model. User model has a name, phone_no, acc_no, ... fields. I wanted to pluck 3 fields i.e name, phone_no and acc_no. For that I am using

```
User.pluck(:name, :phone_no, :acc_no)
```

There is no presence validation on phone_no and acc_no, thats why it gives me following result

```
[
 ['xyz', '1234'],
 ['pqr', '4567', '12345678'],
 ['abc']
]
```

I need result like

```
 [
  ['xyz', '1234', nil],
  ['pqr', '4567', '12345678'],
  ['abc', nil, nil]
 ]
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: can't be. `pluck` **should** return what's in the second code sample, not in the first one.

Comment: it does in my code. OP are you sure you are not using some `compact` somewhere?

Comment: Do you use mongoDB? Try my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
User.only(:name, :phone_no, :acc_no).map { |u| [u.name, u.phone_no, u.acc_no] }
```